# How take id from EF for DTO?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, service, repository, dto

I use an architecture with services -> repository when repository returns DTO objects.

In normal code repository add looks like:

```
_context.Set<ModelType>().Add(model);
return model;
```

and in service, I can invoke SaveChanges and my model populated by new ID.

But in my case, I have to do a lot of moves.

```
var model = Mapper.Map<ModelType>(dtoModel);
_context.Set<ModelType>().Add(model);
_context.SaveChanges();
return model.MapTo<DtoModelType>();
```

But it is very bad because repository shouldn't have SaveChanges inside repository.

We did some improvement so we added saveChanges argument into Add method:

```
Add(Model model, bool saveChanges)
```

But we still have the SaveChanges inside repository

Comment: "repository shouldn't have SaveChanges inside repository" Why not?

Comment: Repository pattern is like a collection. List.Add(item) List.Delete(item2) - so now the collection has one item added and one deleted, but only in the collection(memory) if we want to save this state we need to invoke a method like Complete() and some system takes collection and save this state to some storage. I always think like this. It is more SOLID - single responsibility principle and we can do a transaction. Also if a repository uses some third-party library etc.